# Retrieve Specific Value In Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a list of users in Firebase that looks like this...

[image]

How would I retrieve only the email (for example) values?

Comment: Two things. 1) Please copy and paste your structure instead of a picture so we don't have to retype it  2) This is a very basic query in Firebase and fully explained in the [Most Excellent Guide to Retrieving Data In Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html). Scroll down the query section and there are a couple of examples that are very similar to what you are asking for.

Comment: @Jay Could you please make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THE answer.

Two things.

1) Please copy and paste your structure instead of a picture so we don't have to retype it. Please take a minute to format it so it looks cool.

2) This is a very basic query in Firebase and fully explained in the [Most Excellent Guide to Retrieving Data In Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html)

Scroll down the query section and there are a couple of examples that are very similar to what you are asking for.

And a tad more info. Doing a query will retrieve each child node that matches the query (including the other stuff within the node). It's up to your code to grab each email (pretty simple task as it's key:value pairs)

If you don't want the other stuff, you would need to change the structure of the data

```
asdf
   firstName
   lastName
   etc

emails
   asdf
    email: email address
   asdf1
    email: email address
```

or, use events: value for example and a structure like this

```
emails
  asdf: email address
  asdf1: email address
```

Comment: Ok I'll go try that, but when I copy and paste my structure it doesn't look good.

Comment: Ok this worked! Thank you. Sorry, I'm new to Firebase, I used Parse.com before this, until Facebook announced it was being shut down.